# How do I migrate InfluxDb to SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, database-migration, influxdb

We have been trying to migrate InfluxDb to SQL Server. Since InfluxDb is time series database, the time will be the primary key. But in SQL Server we are using GUID as the primary key. Is there any way to migrate large data sets from Influx to SQL Server using column mapping? We cannot insert manually as there is huge data in influx.

Comment: Yes, with conversion work, specific to your database model and application. `in SQL Server we are using GUID as the primary key.` don't use a GUID then. That's a bad idea to begin with unless you use take precautions to avoid hopelessly fragmenting the table and index (ie never use `NEWID()`)

Comment: It's impossible to help with this question as there's no information apart from a possible design bug (using GUIDs) that doesn't have anything to do with time-series anyway. Just because you use one ID type in one table doesn't mean you have to use it everywhere. SQL Server has an entire ETL system (SSIS) which can pull data from any ODBC source, flat files, and up to a point HTTP services. If you can export the data from InfluxDB, SQL Server can import it.

Comment: On the other hand, time-series databases are used to ingest and process real-time data. They're far better at this than any RDBMS system, including SQL extensions specific for this job. If you want to calculate, eg a running total or average of current data, the time-series database is better. You'd need to export data to SQL Server if you wanted to perform *other* types of queries.

Comment: If you want to use SQL Server as a time-series database you'd have to use an in-memory table at least to ingest data without concurrency issues. You'd have to rewrite your queries to provide the same functionality InfluxDB does. Exporting the data is probably the easiest part.